# Centering element in LaTeX table with fixed column width

Tags: latex

I am having some problems with LaTeX tables. In particular, I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.15\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}|}
        \hline
         & \textbf{Virtual Reality Experience} & \textbf{First Person Experience} & \textbf{Multimedia Presentation Experience} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Full sample}} \\ 
         \hline
         & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{\%} \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Gender} &&&&& \\
         Female & 12 & 10 & 18 & 40 & 52.6 \\
         Male & 10 & 13 & 13 & 36 & 47.4 \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Educational level} &&&&& \\
         High School & 8 & 5 & 6 & 19 & 25.0 \\
         Bachelor's Degree & 13 & 9 & 19 & 41 & 53.9 \\
         Master's Degree & 1 & 8 & 6 & 15 & 19.7 \\
         PhD & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1.3 \\
         \hline \hline
         \textbf{Age} &&&&& \\
         Mean & 23.6 & 24.6 & 24 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24.1} \\
         Median & 23.6 & 24.6 & 24 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24.1} \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Participants demographic information}
    \label{tab:demographic}
\end{table}
```

This code gives me the following output:
[generated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y3Vf.png).

I would like to center also the last column (using, like in the other columns, `>{\centering}` ). However, when I try to do so, I have a lot of errors:

- > Misplaced `\noalign` - You have used a `\hline` command in the wrong place, probably outside a table. If the `\hline` command is written inside a table, try including `\\` before it **(on the 3rd `\hline` )**
- > Extra alignment tab has been changed to `\cr` - You have written too many alignment tabs in a table, causing one of them to be turned into a line break. Make sure you have specified the correct number of columns in your table **(on the `\textbf{Gender}` line)**
- > LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end - You have used a `\\` or `\newline` command where LaTeX was not expecting one. Make sure that you only use line breaks after blocks of text, and be careful using linebreaks inside lists and other environments **(on the `\textbf{Gender}` line)**

Could anyone help me? The table is far more beautiful if I manage to center also the last line.

Comment: Next time please make a [mre] so we don't have to guess which packages you might load

Comment: Also please post latex error messages in unabridged (including linebreaks) as code blocks. The linebreaks *are* important as they denote where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can centre the last column with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{
      |
      p{0.15\textwidth}
      >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
      >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
      >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
      >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}
      >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.15\textwidth}
      |
    }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Virtual Reality Experience} & \textbf{First Person Experience} & \textbf{Multimedia Presentation Experience} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Full sample}} \\ 
         \hline
         & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{n} & \textit{\%} \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Gender} &&&&& \\
         Female & 12 & 10 & 18 & 40 & 52.6 \\
         Male & 10 & 13 & 13 & 36 & 47.4 \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Educational level} &&&&& \\
         High School & 8 & 5 & 6 & 19 & 25.0 \\
         Bachelor's Degree & 13 & 9 & 19 & 41 & 53.9 \\
         Master's Degree & 1 & 8 & 6 & 15 & 19.7 \\
         PhD & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1.3 \\
         \hline \hline
         \textbf{Age} &&&&& \\
         Mean & 23.6 & 24.6 & 24 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24.1} \\
         Median & 23.6 & 24.6 & 24 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{24.1} \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Participants demographic information}
    \label{tab:demographic}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]